# Weird behaviour when using Entity Framework to inserting data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm quite confused why this thing is happening when inserting data using Entity Framework.

[image]

[image]

Please look closely at the `MerchantId` and the `OwnersInformationId`, the first set had a different ID's but after `context.SaveChanges()`, the `OwnersInformationId` will be the same as the `MerchantId`.

Any idea why this is happening ?

I have a class like this:

```
public class Merchant
{
    public Guid MerchantId { get; set; }
    public virtual OwnersInformation OwnersInformation { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show complete code,where are you inserting guid ?possibly you are inserting same values in both column

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI no, I doubt that's the case because I have 1 successful insert with a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I solved it by doing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OwnersInformation>()
            .HasKey(o => o.MerchantId);
```

By the way, if you guys are wondering I'm not the one who started the project everything is already set and I didn't notice it fast enough. Cheers!